# Waiting for response from firebase in angularJS

Tags: angularjs, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am new to firebase and I am using new console to simply demonstrate saving, retrieving data from firebase real time database. On retrieving the data, I am connecting it to a model to show it on the screen in list format. But the screen doesn't show anything. I want to use promise to wait until I get the data from the firebase database.

```
app.factory('Authentication', ['$rootScope', function($rootScope) {
return {
     getUsers: function() {
        firebase.database().ref('/userInfo').on('value', function (snapshot) {
           return snapshot.val();
        });
     }
   }
}
```

How do I use promise to wait until the data is fetched.

```
app.controller('myController', function($scope, $rootScope, Authentication) {
   $scope.userData = Authentication.getUsers();
}
```

Comment: try using q you can find it in npm

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you should install q or download and add the script

1) `npm install q --save`

2) add this to your app module like adding `'q'`

3) add q to your factory and use deffer

```
app.factory('Authentication', ['$rootScope','q', function($rootScope, q) {
return {
     getUsers: function() {
        var defer = q.defer();
        firebase.database().ref('/userInfo').on('value', function (snapshot) { //assuming you get snapshot value from the db
           defer.resolve(snapshot.val());
           //return snapshot.val();
        });
     return defer.promise;
     }
   }
}
```

4) then add then to your function

```
app.controller('myController', function($scope, $rootScope, Authentication) {
   Authentication.getUsers().then(function(snap){
       $scope.userData = snap;
   });
}
```

you can also add defer .reject to return err and you catch it in other function in your code

for example

```
app.factory('Authentication', ['$rootScope','q', function($rootScope, q) {
return {
     getUsers: function() {
        var defer = q.defer();
        firebase.database().ref('/userInfo').on('value', function (snapshot) {
           if(!snapshot.val()){
                defer.reject('err no data');
           }else{
                defer.resolve(snapshot.val());
                //return snapshot.val();
           }
        });
     return defer.promise;
     }
   }
}
```

and here you do

```
app.controller('myController', function($scope, $rootScope, Authentication) {
   Authentication.getUsers().then(function(snap){
       $scope.userData = snap;
   }, function(err){
       //do something with the error
   });
}
```

hope it helped

**note**

as you know js is asynchronous.
so when we need to wait for response and it take time js continue to do his stuff. so we need the promise to make sure we get the response before he goes to the next step (that we want him to go)

A promise in the Javascript and AngularJS world is an assurance that we will get a result from an action at some point in the future;
thats the resolve and reject

for more info read this article

[promise](http://haroldrv.com/2015/02/understanding-angularjs-q-service-and-promises/)

hope it hepled

Comment: Thanks a lot! It worked. But as I am new to these promises, can you explain it a bit?

Comment: While this works, I would highly recommend looking into using the AngularFire library, developed by the Firebase team.  See my answer for more details. https://github.com/firebase/angularfire

Comment: There is no need for the q library as Angular ships with $q. Firebase also returns a promise from the `.once()` function.

Answer (score 0):

**[Use AngularFire](https://github.com/firebase/angularfire)**

You're not seeing anything on the screen because you're trying to return from an async function.

Also, Angular uses a dirty checking system to tell when values have changed and to re-render the screen. The Firebase library by itself has no way to triggering this dirty checking system. This is why you should use the officially supported AngularFire library.

```
// Initialize Firebase
var config = {
  apiKey: "<your-api-key>",
  authDomain: "<your-auth-domain>",
  databaseURL: "https://<your-database-url>.firebaseio.com",
  storageBucket: "",
};
firebase.initializeApp(config);
angular.module('app', ['firebase'])
  .constant('FirebaseUrl', config.databaseURL)
  .controller('MyCtrl', MyController)
  .config(function($firebaseRefProvider, FirebaseUrl) {
     $firebaseRefProvider.registerUrl(FirebaseUrl);
  });

function MyController($scope, $firebaseRef, $firebaseArray) {
  var usersRef = $firebaseRef.child('userInfo');
  $scope.users = $firebaseArray(usersRef);
}
```

Comment: I need to use this from now. Thanks for the awesome suggestion!!